# Update a Single Field of Object in Object Array in Javascript/Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, lodash

Is there a way to update a single field in an object within an array of objects?

```
PeopleList= [
   {id:1, name:"Mary", active:false}, 
   {id:2, name:"John", active:false}, 
   {id:3, name:"Ben", active:true}]
```

For instance, setting John's active to true.

I tried to do this in Lodash but it doesn't return a proper result. It returns a lodash wrapper.

```
        updatedList = _.chain(PeopleList)
       .find({name:"John"})
       .merge({active: true});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well you don't even need `lodash` for this with es6:

```
PeopleList.find(people => people.name === "John").active = true;
//if the record might not exist, then
const john = PeopleList.find(people => people.name === "John")
if(john){
  john.active = true;
}
```

Or if you don't want to mutate the original list

```
const newList = PeopleList.map(people => {
  if(people.name === "John") {
    return {...people, active: true};
  }
  return {...people};
});
```

Comment: I think Lodash is better for a beginner, so they don't have to deal with transpilation.

Answer (score 13):

`_.find(PeopleList, { name: 'John' }).active = true`